# spring security OAuth user based

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth

I have some GET operation in a rest controller where i would like the user to not only be Authenticated based on role but also authorized to perform operation on that account.

Example to get photo, user should not only have correct role but should only retrieve his/her photo. In the DB i have userid with each photo.

```
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('read')").
@RequestMapping(value="/photo/{userid}/photoid/{photoid}")
```

I have implemented OAuth2 based authentication(grant type password) and its working fine in resource server.Is there a way i could attached userid in grantedAuthorities and have it validated that {photoid} belongs to given user id before method with annotation above is executed.